# Unlock Folder / Drive - when locked by VBA

Tags: vba

After creating and moving files by VBA, a significant proportion of these seem to be locked and cant be moved or renamed.

I have found a number of codes that will unlock a particular file, but not a whole folder or drive. The below is meant to unlock any folder in Sheet1!A1, but does not currently work.

Has anyone had a similar issues, and know any code that can unlock an entire folder?

```
Sub Unlock_Folder()

'Get File Handle

Dim fHandle As Long

fHandle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2)

'Close the Handle

CloseHandle fHandle
```

End Sub

Comment: Have never seen this happen - maybe you could expand with a bit more detail on exactly how you ended up with locked files/folders.

Comment: I dont know how I ended up with the locked files, I created folders with a macro, at one point it crashed, which I suspect is the issue, however now there are duplicate folders that I can not delete. Error message is saying that the file is still open in another program even whenexcel process has been terminated. No other files should be accessing the sheets.

Comment: If you reboot that should clear any hanging processes

Comment: I tried that, but as its a virtual machine running windows server the process could be anywhere. It has a strange mirror folder as well, which is basically a copy of all the existing files.